# Empty set in a jitclass attribute

Tags: python, class, set, numba

I need to create a `set` as a `jitclass` attribute, and it must start empty:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.jitclass([('foo', nb.types.Set(nb.f8))])
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = set()

b = Bar()
```

But it fails because numba doesn't know the type of the objects contained by the temporary `set` variable:

```
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Cannot infer the type of variable '$0.2' (temporary variable),
have imprecise type: set(undefined).
```

This works though:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.jitclass([('foo', nb.types.Set(nb.f8))])
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = {0.}
        self.foo.clear()

b = Bar()
```

But the solution is really ugly. Is there a better way to initialize the empty `set`?

I'm using Python 3.6 and Numba 0.45.1

Comment: This seems like a "feature request" that probably also belongs on the [numba issue tracker](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues).

Comment: Yes, I expected to find something like [numba.typed.Dict.empty()](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html?highlight=dict%20empty#dict), but as of Numba 0.64 they still say it's an experimental feature. So it will take longer to have a "numba.typed.Set.empty()".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot instantiate empty "Python classes" in the `__init__` of `jitclass`es. The same problem happens (as of numba 0.45.1) also with lists:

```
@nb.jitclass([('foo', nb.types.List(nb.f8))])
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = []
```

> ```
> TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
> Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
> Cannot infer the type of variable '$0.1' (temporary variable), have imprecise type: list(undefined).
> ```

The problem here is that numba infers the type by analyzing the just the function body. It doesn't take the specification of the class into account.

---

Personally I would create a function-wrapper to create the empty set, that way it's easier to change the code if (or when) numba decides to implement creating empty sets based on the signature/specification:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def create_empty_set_float64():
    aset = {1.}
    aset.clear()
    return aset

@nb.jitclass([('foo', nb.types.Set(nb.f8))])
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = create_empty_set_float64()

b = Bar()
```

Comment: This seems to be the proper approach while there is nothing like Dict.empty() for sets.